# JDBC in Java MysqlDataSource

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on JDBC and using MySqlDataSource to connect. How do I create a schema before adding the schema name in DataSource.setDataBaseName()? Connection is OK and I can execute updates and so on, but only if I manually create schema/database in MysqlWorkbench

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBHandler {

private String user = "root";
private String serverName = "localhost";
private String dbName = "TimeEdit";
private Connection connection;
private MysqlDataSource datasource = new MysqlDataSource();

public DBHandler(String passw) throws SQLException {
    datasource.setPassword(passw);
    datasource.setUser(user);
    datasource.setServerName(serverName);
    datasource.setDatabaseName(dbName);
    //datasource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://<localhost>:<3306>/");
    
}

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return datasource.getConnection();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at Flyway or Liquibase.

Comment: "but only if i manually create Schema/database". That's how I like to do it.

Comment: thanks,, but i solved it ;)  I had to run a query: "set <database_name>" statement.executeupdate(query) in each method i was running after i created the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by executing a query: "set <database_name>" statement.executeupdate(query) in each method i was running after i created the schema.

Comment: You should not execute `set <database_name>` on a MySQL connection, but instead use `setCatalog(..)`. Using `set <database_name>` can bring the JDBC connection in an inconsistent state. See also the MySQL Connector/J documentation, specifically the [Connection URL syntax - `database`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html#idm45129599265488)